# What is an algorithm to detect whether all my game pieces are surrounded by nonadjacent enemy pieces?

Tags: algorithm

I'm implementing a game in java where the goal is to reach the gameboard's edge. Therefore, if all of one player's pieces are surrounded by not-necessarily-adjacent enemy pieces so that they cannot reach the edge of the board after any number of moves, that player loses.

I'm stumped trying to develop an algorithm to check for this condition. I have approached looking at conditions of both the enemies and the surrounded pieces and made no good progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filling-method. I am assuming you have some kind of board where game pieces are placed. We will use additional pieces of a third color. If there is white and black, lets say your third color is red.

This is one possible algorihtm for white:

Step 1: If there are no empty spaces around the positions of white (or red, see below), you are done: either white is at the border or its surrounded. Return answer (and remove all red pieces, again see below).

Step 2: Find an empty spot (there must be one otherwise you would have ended in step 1), add a red color at the spot. Go back to Step 1.

Answer (score -1):

A Delaunay Triangulation gives you the adjacency information of a set of points in arbitrary spatial distribution. There are libraries to do this.

The geometric dual of Delaunay Triangulation is called Voronoi Diagram. The latter concept is maybe a bit easier to understand at first.

In the image you see the Delaunay Triangulation in black, and the Voronoi Diagram in red.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Delaunay_Voronoi.svg